# Vs 10 VB.net Ms access database dbnull value while selecting

Tags: ms-access-2007, vb.net-2010

ok so i added a Ms access table to the vb.net application
then i made a filter
that table contains come columns with DBNull values
the problem is that whenever i start writing anything in the filtering which have a cell with dbnull value it gets me that error

"""    The value for column 'Postion' in table 'Parts' is DBNull.   """

and the exception details is 
"""""""""""""""""

```
System.Data.StrongTypingException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The value for column 'Postion' in table 'Parts' is DBNull.
  Source=Erkat
  StackTrace:
       at Erkat.cutterprogDataSet.PartsRow.get_Postion() in C:\Users\Mina\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Erkatpj\Erkat\cutterprogDataSet.Designer.vb:line 2634
  InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
       Message=Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.
       Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToString(Object Value)
            at Erkat.cutterprogDataSet.PartsRow.get_Postion() in C:\Users\Mina\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Erkatpj\Erkat\cutterprogDataSet.Designer.vb:line 2632
       InnerException:
```

"""""""""""""""""""

i found a solution but its only temporary one

in the designer AUTO GENERATED code

"""

```
   <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")>  _
    Public Property Postion() As String
        Get
            Try 
                Return CType(Me(Me.tableParts.PostionColumn),String)
            Catch e As Global.System.InvalidCastException
                Throw New Global.System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'Postion' in table 'Parts' is DBNull.", e)
            End Try
        End Get
        Set
            Me(Me.tableParts.PostionColumn) = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

"""
i changed it to

""""""""""""""""""""""

```
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
         Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")>  _
        Public Property Postion() As String
            Get
                Try
                    If Convert.IsDBNull(Me(Me.tableParts.PostionColumn)) Then
                        Return Nothing
                    Else
                        Return CType(Me(Me.tableParts.PostionColumn), String)

                    End If

                Catch e As Global.System.InvalidCastException
                    Throw New Global.System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column 'Postion' in table 'Parts' is DBNull.", e)
                End Try
            End Get
            Set
                Me(Me.tableParts.PostionColumn) = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

"""""""""""""""""""""""
but since its auto generate it keeps on deleting it and making the old one again

can anyone please help??

Answer (score 0):

Store `Public Property Postion() As String` as an `Object` and cast to a `String` if `Position` is not `DBNull.Value` or `Nothing`.

```
Public Property Postion() As Object
    Get
        Return Me(Me.tableParts.PostionColumn
    End Get
    Set
        Me(Me.tableParts.PostionColumn) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Usage:

```
Dim pos as String
Dim obj as Object = Position
If Not (obj Is Nothing) And Not (obj = DBNull.Value) Then
  pos = CType(obj, String)
  ' Alternately:
  ' pos = CString(obj)
  ' Or:
  ' pos = obj.ToString()
Else
  pos = String.Empty
End If
```

My VB is not so good, so please forgive if there are grammar issues.